# Unable to run a .bat or .ps1 file to copy a file from one server to another in PHP

Tags: php, iis

I'll try to be as clear as possible because my problem is quite complicated.
I have an application divided into 2 projects.
Both projects are hosted on an IIS Express server running on Windows Server 2022.
Everything is developed in PHP and JS.

There's a big project that does several things like creating a report or taking photos.
This project runs on an internal server, not accessible from the outside, connected to a SQL Server database.
The second project runs on a DMZ server, accessible from the outside, not connected to any database.
The second project is solely used to view reports and photos, so it communicates with the first one by sending PHP requests (CURL). The first project retrieves all the information and sends back the page to display in the response.
All of this is working well.

Now, I want the user to be able to export the photos.
So, in the first project, using PHPWord, I created a .docx file that contains the photos, and it's saved on the server.
My problem is that I need to save it on the DMZ server (the second project's server) so that the user can download it, but it's impossible to do due to permission issues.

So, I thought about creating a .bat or .ps1 file (on the internal server where the Word file is saved) to copy the Word file from one server to another and execute this file in PHP after saving the Word file.

My problem is that I can't get PHP to execute this file at all. I've tried everything, all the commands I found on the internet don't work; I'm getting a permission error, I believe.
However, when I'm on the server and double-click on the .bat or .ps1 file, the file copies instantly.
Another solution I tried was creating a scheduled task in Windows to run the .bat file. When I manually run the task, the copy happens, but it doesn't execute in PHP.
That's what I've tested so far :

```
// $command = "cmd /c C:/www/dunfreshSQ/robocopy.bat";
// $command = "c:/WINDOWS/system32/cmd /c START C:/www/dunfreshSQ/robocopy.bat";
// $command = 'powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File robocopy.ps1';
// $command = 'powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "copy-item.ps1"';
// $command = 'C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /run /tn "CopyPhotosContainer"';
$output = exec($command);
echo $output;
```

Comment: `I believe`...because? What have you done to try and find out? We can't see your environment

Comment: and this has what to do with [javascript] tag?

Comment: PHP will run your script with the same exact credentials as regular PHP code, so I don't think there's any benefit over good old [copy()](https://php.net/copy). Regarding [exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), it has two optional arguments to gather more information, you may want to try them. Last but not least, `echo` casts stuff to string so it'll mask boolean falses; you can use `var_dump()` instead.

Comment: I tried in both directions, from server A to server B and then from server B to server A. The PowerShell script works when I run it manually, for example, from A to B:

robocopy C:\www\dunfreshSQ\FICHIERS \\dunhqweb01\fichiers /r:1 photos_container.docx

But when I run the command in PHP using shell_exec(), I get the following error:

ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Getting File System Type of Destination \\dunhqweb01\fichiers\ Access is denied.

Comment: So then, you need to give permission on the fileshare to the account which php runs under (which will be set by IIS)

Comment: Make sure the user account under which the IIS Express server is running (usually the "IIS_IUSRS" group) has the necessary permissions to access and execute the script.

Comment: @YurongDai 
how to do this ?

Comment: Navigate to the directory where the script is located. Right-click the script file and select Properties. Enter the "Security" tab and click the "Edit" button to modify the permissions. Click the Add button and enter a name for the IIS Express user or group (for example, "IIS_IUSRS"). Click Check Names to verify the user or group name. After verification, click OK to add it. In the permission settings, make sure the user or group has at least "Read and Execute" permissions on the script file.